# Custom tiles with leaflet in R

Tags: r, leaflet

I've been trying to follow the instructions on [Using custom tiles in an RStudio Leaflet map](https://rpubs.com/walkerke/custom_tiles)

First I use `gdal2tiles` to generate my custom tiles

```
gdal2tiles -p mercator -s EPSG:32610 -z 2-18 -a 0,0,0 ortho_aoi.tif orthoTiles
```

Then I uploaded the tiles to my [git repo](https://github.com/AndyPL22/projectSasquatch).

And then I try and load them in leaflet in R and... nothing

```
leaflet() %>% addTiles("http://AndyPL22.github.io/projectSasquatch/data/orthoTiles/{z}/{x}/{y}.png", 
options = tileOptions(tms = TRUE, minZoom = 2, maxZoom = 18))
```

Seems like it should be straightforward. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The R code works fine, the problem must lie in the `gdal2tiles` code where you generate your tiles.